# How to detect which action closed the colorbox

Tags: jquery, colorbox

How can we detect which action closed the colorbox? I want to run specific code only when user closes colorbox by clicking on close icon on top right (and not by pressing escape key)

I have used jQuery to open my colorbox on page load. Below I have used onClosed event to detect which key was used. However it shows error 'cannot read property 'keycode' of undefined' even if I pressed Escape key to close the colorbox.

```
 $(document).ready(function() 
{
  $.colorbox({href:'#my_hidden_div', inline:true, width:'500px', height:'500px', 
                onClosed:function(e){
                   alert(e.keycode); // not showing value even for Esc key!
                 }
              });
});
```

To start with, in above example, I am trying to read the keycode to detect which key user has pressed to close it.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HHDDn/2/) with my example.

Comment: David - I am getting 'undefined' when I alert e.keycode

Comment: I think there is some big misunderstanding.. I just read your comment where you mentioned 'e.keycode will tell you the keycode of the keyboard button...'. However, I am not getting the actual keycode in my example. Hence I informed that to you. I hope this clears my comment more?

Comment: You are right.. I might have provided less info at the beginning, My Mistake.. may be because I am a beginner in jquery & colorbox both. I certainly like to provide enough info in my questions though :) I have just added more correct info in my question to help the readers understand it better.

Answer (score 2):

I would try checking for the target of the click like so:

```
 $.colorbox({href:'#my_hidden_div', inline:true, width:'500px', height:'500px', 
            onClosed:function(e){
               var closeBtn = document.getElementById( 'your close buttons id' );
               if ( e && e.target && e.target === closeBtn ) {
                 // do something
               }
             }
          });
```